# Mongoose query returns error, but error is the result I am looking for

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In Mongoose, when I call the below code:

```
db.Person.find({}).then((err, author) => {
   if (err) {
     console.log("err",err);
   } else {
    console.log('author', author);
    }
  });
```

it returns an error and not the document I am looking for and the error appears to be the document I was looking for. See here: [image]

Why would it return an error instead of the actual object? I was trying to access properties from the document that was returned. The object exists in my database:
[image]

Comment: I corrected my answer, your .then is backward

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
You should use a query.exec() to get a full promise:

```js
// `.exec()` gives you a fully-fledged promise
var promise = query.exec();

promise.then(function (doc) {
  // use doc
});
```

When you use it like a promise,

```js
.then((doc)=>console.log(doc))
```

doc is the actual document, an eventual error would be in

```js
.catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.then()` and the promise is resolved then you would get the result in the `then()`.

```
.then((result) => console.log(result))
```

when the promise is rejected you can catch the error in:

```
.catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

Promise has three phases `resolve` , `reject` and `pending`.